# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://js.stripe.com/v2/' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: in opencart

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments, opencart

In stripe payment gateway ,, This is shows as a error
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://js.stripe.com/v2/' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 2):

This is a URL to a library. If you get a CORS error, that means you tried to load it via `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch`, and the Stripe server is not designed to serve this library via a cross-origin request. Rather add this in your HTML `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>`

Comment: This doesn't work either for my case.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Javascript Library, please use this in your code to integrate Stripe Payment Gateway from your HTML File.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```